# Does sisense elasticube support nosql database structure?

Tags: sisense

I have to load data in the Sisense ElasticCube data model from MongoDB, the MongoDB collection has data structure as below.

```
 {
    "FirstName": "Dilip",
    "LastName": "Singh",
    "Address":
    [{
            "Address1": "E-34",
            "Address2": "New Ashoknagar",
            "City": "East Delhi",
            "State": "Delhi",
            "Country": "India"
        }, {
            "Address1": "D2098",
            "Address2": "14th Avenue",
            "City": "Gaurcity",
            "State": "Noida",
            "Country": "India"
        }
    ],
    "Designation": "Sr. System Analyst"
}
```

I found the Address missing from Sisense Data Model. I followed this link https://documentation.sisense.com/latest/managing-data/connectors/mongo-db.htm#gsc.tab=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sisense does support NoSQL from MongoDB via the MongoDB Data Connector. They claim "MongoDB is a NoSQL, schema-less database. Using this connector you can run any SQL query directly on MongoDB to make sense of your unstructured data."

[MongoDB Data Connector](https://www.sisense.com/data-connectors/mongodb/)